# How to see why my server is restarted without user action

Tags: linux, redhat

My server is restarted by itself tonight. How can I determine waht caused this? I checked in /var/log/messages but I can't understand from there.

Is there any other way/option ?

I use Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 5)

Thanks

Comment: All other issues aside, RHEL is now well past end-of-life, and as a result any number of exploitable situations might arise.  You are aware of this, yes?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you trying to say ? I don't decide on my own what distribution to use..

Comment: Your server is past end-of-life on the OS.  If there were, say, remotely-exploitable bugs which could be used to trigger remote reboots, they won't be patched by Red Hat.  If you think there might be a problem with this server, getting it onto an up-to-date version of the OS (RHEL 5, or better, 6; or if budget is an issue, CentOS 6) is pretty much a first step, if the availability of this server is important to you.

Comment: I don't think the problem is from version.

Comment: I don't want to appear catty, but you don't know where the problem is, or you wouldn't be asking here.  If you're looking for a minefield, it's important not to drive past the big signs on the right saying "MINEFIELD" just because you're sure the field is over to the left.

Comment: I meant that this server is in private network, behind firewall and will be very hard on someone to reach it remotely if don't have rights. Budget is not a problem (company has money) but you know how is in big companys. A lot of paperwork, plannings, projects etc before something happen. So may be some day we will update version or will be other distribution, I don't know at the momment. All I want is to see why this happen today. They are 3 servers and only this one is restarted.

Comment: I have some servers like that.  The HA pairs fail every 497 days because they're running a really old Linux where the uptime clock resets every 497 days or so, and that causes the HA logic to fail hard, so every box tries to be primary at the same time.  My point is that once bugs are no longer being fixed, the oddest things can cause systems to fail, and finding out why can be very painful and time-consuming; in my case, it took about three years to work out what was happening.  I hope you get lucky.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I'll try somehow to see what happen.

Comment: What hardware is this running on?

Comment: @MadHatter: What's the magic number associated with 497 days ?

Comment: Ah.  Umm.  If memory serves, it's the jiffies counter rolling off the end of a 32-bit integer.  Since the normal jiffy is 10ms, 2**32 of them is 497.103 days.  And if you're curious, it never got fixed for the same reasons of project inertia that the OP quotes: for the past few years, I've rebooted all those boxes on New Year's Eve, and I will again this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess:

Your server is restarting because some piece of hardware in it is failing. It is, after all, an antique that should have been decommissioned years ago. The symptom you describe is also strongly correlated with failed hardware components, regardless of the age of the system.

Comment: Acording to alarms all components are healthy and runing normaly.But probably is some device is failed. Other co-worker investigate this now.